# Android arm64 standalone toolchain only available from platform 21 onwards for 4.9 Toolchain Version

Tags: android, android-ndk, toolchain

We are building a arm64 standalone toolchain to build ssl with. For the 4.8 Toolchain version this worked fine:

```
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --toolchain=aarch64-linux-android-4.8 --install-dir=${CURRENTPATH}/bin/android-toolchain-arm64 --arch=arm64
```

For the 4.9 Toolchain version the it only builds for platform 21 or newer

```
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-21 --toolchain=aarch64-linux-android-4.9 --install-dir=${CURRENTPATH}/bin/android-toolchain-arm64 --arch=arm64
```

When Trying to build for platform 9 - 20 it gives no errors, but the folder is not created.

Is there a workaround for this or do we have to change our build scripts to only support Android 21 and newer for arm64 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was mistaken. We did always build the arm64 toolchain with platform 21.

It is confusing that the creation of the toolchain does not create an error when created with a platform < 21. The script simply finishes but nothing happens.

In short arm64 toolchain can only be build with platform 21 and above. This should usually not be a problem since arm64 devices usually are newer and probably have a android that is newer as 21.

I will leave this question up in case anybody runs into the same issue not being able to build the toolchain.